Use ifelse for several columns in R
My goal is to create a binary variable (k) that turns 1 if in any column between mpg and wt the values 3.90 and/or 160.0 appears.
Code
library(tidyverse)


mtcars<-mtcars%>%
  mutate(k=ifelse(mpg:wt==3.90|mpg:wt==160.0,1,0))


Result
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `k = ifelse(mpg:wt == 3.9 | mpg:wt == 160, 1, 9)`.
Caused by error:
! `k` must be size 32 or 1, not 19.


Maybe you can play rowSums like below
mtcars %>%
    mutate(k = +(rowSums(across(mpg:wt, ~ .x %in% c(3.9, 160))) > 0))

such that
> mtcars %>%
+     mutate(k = +(rowSums(across(mpg:wt, ~ .x %in% c(3.9, 160))) > 0))
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb k
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 0
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 0
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 0
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 0
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 0
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 0
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 0
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 0
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 0
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 0
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 0
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 0
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 0
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 0
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 0
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 0
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 0
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 0
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 0
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 0
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 0
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 0
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 0
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 0
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 0
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 0
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 0
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 0
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 0
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 0


1) rowwise/any Proceeding row by row check if any of the columns are in the key values and convert to numeric.
library(dplyr)

mtcars%>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(k = +any(c_across(mpg:wt) %in% c(3.90, 160.0))) %>%
  ungroup

2) if_any if_any applies the function specified in the second argument to each column and then takes the or of the columns row-wise.
mtcars %>% mutate(k = +if_any(mpg:wt, ~ .x %in% c(3.9, 160.0)))

It could also be written like this:
mtcars %>% mutate(k = +if_any(mpg:wt, `%in%`, c(3.9, 160.0)))


Add if_any solution.
